# 数式の変形の過程について

Tags: アルゴリズム, 数学

下記数式についてです。
上の式から下の式に変形する過程や数学的な性質が理解できません。
数学に弱くお恥ずかしいですのですが、ご解説いただければ幸いです。

[image: 数式]

▼分からない箇所
下記の1/n^2Σnが1/nΣ1になる式（下記画像の1行目、2行目）になる箇所がわかりませんでした。
また、最終式についてなのですがシグマ通しの足し算はシグマの左側（今回でいうところの1/n^2同士も足せる認識で問題ないでしょうか。当たり前のことかもしれませんが数学が苦手で腑におちませんでした。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

参照：新情報/通信システム工学　データ構造とアルゴリズム

Answer (score 3):

とりあえず高校で学んだことが理解出来てると仮定して説明をつくりました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
もし分からないことがあればまた質問してください。

【3/18 19:25追記】
説明の画像における3行目の最初の`Σ`が`1`から`n-1`になっていますが`0`から`n-1`の間違いですね。申し訳ありません。

【3/20 07:40追記】
2つの質問の後者は恐らくこういうことを質問しているのではないかと想像して回答しました。
その想像が間違っていたりしたらまた質問おねがいします。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 丁寧な解説ありがとうございませす。
大まかに把握できました。助かりました。
ただ二点分からない箇所がございました。
このコメント欄では見づらいと思いましたので上記の質問欄に記載させていただきました。
よろしければ解説いただければ幸いです。

Comment: 私も追加の質問に対する回答を追記しますね。